# cambiar el idioma del mensaje Exception en try catch c#?

Tags: c#

Como puedo cambiar el mensaje que lanza por default el try catch?
El idioma del equipo por default esta en ingles pero quiero que el mensaje salga en español.

```
try{
//codigo
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
 Message.Show(ex.Message);//este mensaje sale en ingles, quiero que salga en español.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yo no cambiaría el idioma de los mensajes de las excepciones. La realidad de la industria es utilizar todo en Ingles ya que muchas veces la traducción distorsiona el mensaje original. Ademas, si en 1 año el mantenimiento de la app la hace otro equipo es un garrón encontrarte con es este tipo de cosas que se ven tan seguido en sistemas legacy.

Para paliar un poco tu problema, puedes armar un gestor de errores, en donde tengas tipificado los mensajes de error pudiendo poner un mensaje mas "entendible" y concatenando al final el mensaje de la excepción. Recuerda que muchas veces el verdadero error lo describe la `InnerException` por lo que te recomiendo que generes el mensaje de error de forma recursiva.

Un código de rápido y muy sencillo de como podrías hacerlo es el siguiente (se puede mejorar mucho).

```
public class MessageErrors {
  // errores bd
  public static ERROR_100 { get; } = "Error de conexion a la BD";
  public static ERROR_101 { get; } = "Timeout excedido";

  // errores logica X
  public static ERROR_200 { get; } = "xyz";

  public showExceptionMessage(string msg, Exception ex) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine($"Error: {msg}");
    sb.AppendLine("-----------------");
    sb.AppendLine($"Detalle de la excepcion: {ex?.Message || string.Empty}");

    return sb.ToString();
  }
}



// En otra clase
var msjErrors = new MessageErrors();

// codigo
try {
  //algo que lance excepcion 
}
catch (Exception ex) {
  Message.Show(msjErrors.showExceptionMessage(MessageErrors.ERROR_100, ex.Message));
}
```

Por otro lado, podrias mejorar esto y capturar las excepciones diferenciandolas por el tipo... ejemplo si ejecutas una query a una BD esta puede generar varios tipos de excepciones y por cada una mostrar un mensaje personalizado

```
try {
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    command.Connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
      Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}", reader[0], reader[1]));
    }
  }
}
catch (SqlException ex) {
  Message.Show(msjErrors.showExceptionMessage(MessageErrors.ERROR_100, ex.Message));
} 
catch (InvalidCastException ex) {
  Message.Show(msjErrors.showExceptionMessage(MessageErrors.ERROR_103, ex.Message));
} 
catch (IOException ex) {
  Message.Show(msjErrors.showExceptionMessage(MessageErrors.ERROR_105, ex.Message));
} catch (Exception ex) {
  Message.Show(msjErrors.showExceptionMessage(MessageErrors.ERROR_199, ex.Message)); // error generico de bd
}
```

Esta forma de generar los msj de error también ayuda al momento de tener que editarlos ya que todos se encuentran en un uni co lugar y no distribuidos por todo el código.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta añadir lo siguiente en tu `Program.cs`, en el método `main`:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture= new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES");
```

Esto lo que hace es crear un nuevo `CultureInfo` con la cultura de español de España, y asignarsela al hilo de ejecución principal de la aplicación. En teoría de esta manera los mensajes de `Exception` deben aparecer en español.

<sub>Debes añadir `using System.Threading` si no lo tienes ya</sub>

Comment: No cambian de idioma los mensajes, ya puse las lineas y el using en el Main del Program.cs. Estoy usando WinForms con VS 2012 professional.

Comment: Yo no tengo windows en ingles para probar, pero probablemente tu windows no tenga los recursos necesarios en español disponibles. Intenta buscar los recursos de la version de .net que estes usando en español

Comment: y para que quieres que el error sea en español, estos errores son para uso de desarrollo no para los usuarios.

Comment: @MiguelZarate la descripcion del error es importante ya que ahi esta claro cual es el problema.

Comment: @Manny no hace falta ser agresivo, la pregunta de Miguel tiene cierta lógica ya que muchos programadores prefieren personalizar los mensajes de error que reciben los usuarios. No debes tomártelo como un ataque personal, aquí todos estamos para ayudarnos.

Comment: @Pikoh no veo como ayuda el comentario de Miguel, pero bueno.

Comment: @Manny tal vez no ayuda, pero al final lo que quería decirte es similar a lo que te han añadido en otra respuesta. De todas maneras,como te digo, creo que no lo debes tomar como un ataque personal, tienes todo el derecho a discrepar con el, pero siempre de una manera educada, siguiendo el codigo de conducta del sitio. Un saludo y espero que encuentres la solucion a tu problema.